# Xpath display correct results in XMLSpy but null in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, itext7, xfa

I am trying to display all text within text nodes only, within an XFA XML document while ignoring namespaces.

I came up with an Xpath that returns the desired results within XMLSpy with xpath 1.0 but the same Xpath in Java returns **null** for some reason.

```
Xpath = //*[local-name()='text'][string-length(normalize-space(.))>0]
```

```
    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//*[local-name()='text'][string-length(normalize-space(.))>0]");


    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println("This prints null = " + nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
    }
```

XML file wouldn't post here so it can be viewed at the link below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n-v3gzT-3GgxNnYKFUvMPjRQmtnkqcpY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you show at least part of the xml that you are trying to use xpath on?

Comment: For whatever reason I am not able to get the xml to format correctly on here.

Comment: @Bryan Paste it and format as codeblock. Somebody will format it for you if you can't get it right.

Comment: Edit...It is giving me an error saying the coded doesn't appear to be properly formatted and it won't allow me to post.  It may be because the xml is extracted and written to a file so it isn't tabbed properly.

Comment: That or possibly because it is a partial xml so it has nodes that aren't closed?

Comment: @Bryan Hmm dunno. If you just paste it, select the XML, and press the `{}` button... that isn't working? AFAICT that should work.

Comment: Nope, I get the following message regardless if I use the {} button or the code button.

Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: I hosted the XML file on Google Drive and added the link to the question.

Comment: I suspect the problem with Stack Overflow formatting the XML is due to its size.  The XML file you've linked to is >100KB.  Please don't post this much data in questions.  If you could have put together a small XML file which contains enough to reproduce the problem but no more, then your question would have been better.  I also suspect Stack Overflow wouldn't have had problems formatting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it's not the `<text>` elements that contain the values, but their child text nodes.

Replace the line

```
    System.out.println("This prints null = " + nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
```

with

```
    System.out.println("This does not print null = " + nodes.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!

Comment: @Bryan Please accept the answer (click the tick at its upper left) if it resolves your question well.